# How to display the field in a joined table with hook_views_data()

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to figure out how to display a field in a joined table, but documentation isn't that great or obvious.

I have my base custom table with a tid field that ties to the taxonomy_term_data table.  I want to display the term name, based upon my tid field.  How to I specify that name field for display in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a relationship to that table, then add the field from that table to your view.

Comment: I'm creating the view programmatically.  I call views_embed_view() to render it.

Comment: It's the same process with views_embed_view, but done programmatically with the views api.